# How to get single NFT's total volume its price history

Tags: nft

Let's say an NFT have been trading 3 times for price: 1 eth, 5 eth, 12 eth and the result will be 18 eth total price volume.

Is there a API service can get the NFT volume ranking of ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are not may solutions that provides a comprehensive view of the NFT price history. I could find an application named [BitQuery](https://bitquery.io/blog/nft-apis) that is offering a GraphQL based NFT metrics like NFT transfers, NFT senders, NFT transactions etc. Hope it would be helpful.